# Asking an IntentService for information about its queue

Tags: android, intentservice, android-intentservice

I have an IntentService that queues up web service calls that need to be made to my web server.  So each Intent is a web service call to be made.

I'd like to set something up where my application can ask this IntentService if it has any Intents containing a particular piece of data (IE: "Are you already waiting to ask the cloud for x data?  Or do I need to tell you to do it?").

Are there any suggestions on how I might extend IntentService to do this?  Can the Intent queue of an IntentService be traversed?  Or would I need to take the IntentService code and alter it?

The only other idea I have is to add a table to the database and log which calls are in the queue, with each log being removed from the table when completed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Are there any suggestions on how I might extend IntentService to do this? Can the Intent queue of an IntentService be traversed? Or would I need to take the IntentService code and alter it?

Probably the latter, if you really want to examine the actual queue. `IntentService` turns the `Intents` into messages popped on the message queue of a `Looper` via a `HandlerThread`. None of that is exposed through the SDK, though. Fortunately, `IntentService` is fairly short -- not even 150 lines. You could clone it into your own package and make modifications as needed. Just run a diff on the source when new source updates are released in the AOSP repository, so you know if Google performed any major surgery on `IntentService` itself that you might want to take advantage of.

> The only other idea I have is to add a table to the database and log which calls are in the queue, with each log being removed from the table when completed.

It wouldn't even need to be persistent like that, since the `IntentService`'s own queue is not persistent. Just maintain your own FIFO queue in `onStartCommand()`, chaining to the superclass, and popping your `Intent` off the queue at the end of `onHandleIntent()`. This has a chance of getting out of sync with the master queue (e.g., you'll want to use `finally` to ensure you pop the work off your own queue), but you wouldn't have to clone the class.

Comment: Great post. I think I have some good ideas to explore now. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this post. I implemented a version of this class for blocking an Intent from being run if it is already in the queue, but it can easily be tweaked if need be https://gist.github.com/2898452

Comment: Thanks for the working code.  The only addition I made was to add a default isEqual method which uses filterEquals, which then allowed me to override it so that I could compare some Extras past into the intent, since the action for all my intents are the same.  Oh I also called my version UniqueIntentService :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to solve it by overriding onStartCommand.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381915/capturing-intentservice-intents-before-onhandleintent) is a smooth solution in which I found inspiration for a similar problem :)

Comment: But when I looked closer I realize that you posted that question as well :)