# How to access queue of IntentService?

Tags: android, service, intentservice

I have an activity which puts several upload processes into the queue of an IntentService. Now i would like to show a list of the pending and started uploads, and a button to stop an upload.

based on this question [Asking an IntentService for information about its queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357013/asking-an-intentservice-for-information-about-its-queue) i started to implement an external queue but so far i have no idea how to stop a specific task.

Are there any better ways how to manage the queue of an IntentService?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register a BroadCastReceiver("stopUpload") in your IntentService to stop uploading when this intent is received. Trigger that intent from your activity's sendBroadcast("stopUpload").

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you better off with a Service and AsyncTasks ?