# Android IntentService how can i know the number of instances in the running queue ?

Tags: android, intentservice

Is there any way i can find out the number of instances of a Queue for an IntentService ? Secondly can i suspend a particular instance of a IntentService ?

Kind Regards.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357013/asking-an-intentservice-for-information-about-its-queue

Answer (score 0):

You could add a static variable incremented ande decremented at each instantiation / destroy