# IntentService - find number of Intents waiting in the queue

Tags: android, android-service, android-intentservice

In my app I use an IntentService to do some work. I want to find out how many intents are waiting to be processed, as IntentService holds them in a 'work queue' , and sends the next one to `onStartCommand()` as the `onStartCommand` of the previous one has finished.

How can I find out how many Intents are waiting in this 'work queue' ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually It's quite easy: All you need to do is override `onStartCommand(...)` and increment a variable, and decrement it in `onHandleIntent(...)`.

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

 private int waitingIntentCount = 0;

 public MyService() {
  super("MyService");
 }

 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  waitingIntentCount++;
  return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
 }


 @Override
 public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
  waitingIntentCount--;
  //do what you need to do, the waitingIntentCount variable contains
  //the number of waiting intents
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html):

As per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)), the system calls `onHandleIntent(Intent)` when the `IntentService` receives a start request.

So, whenever you add an `Intent` to your queue, you increment and store an `Integer` that will represent the number of `Intent`s in queue:

```
public void addIntent(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int numOfIntents = prefs.getInt("numOfIntents", 0);
    numOfIntents++;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();    
    edit.putInt("numOfIntents",numOfIntents);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Then, each time `onHandleIntent(Intent)` is called you decrease that `Integer` value:

```
public void removeIntent(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int numOfIntents = prefs.getInt("numOfIntents", 0);
    numOfIntents--;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putInt("numOfIntents",numOfIntents);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Finally, whenever you would like to check how many `Intent`s that's in the queue, you simply fetch that value:

```
public void checkQueue(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
    int numOfIntents = prefs.getInt("numOfIntents",0);
    Log.d("debug", numOfIntents);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `onHandleIntent` (did you mean `onStartCommand` ?) Is only called  when the 'previous'  `onHandleIntent` has finished. Either way, this is kind of a hack, is there no way to access the intent queue directly? Also, why store the integer in sharedPreferences, and not just a private (static ?) variable  in the IntentService class?

Comment: I did a little research on this, and could not find any "official" way of achieving your goal. It could be a static variable, but then you could only access it from the Service class (I think), with `SharedPreference` you can access it from your whole application. @JonasCz

Comment: I think you could replace `onHandleIntent` with `onStartCommand`

Comment: Ok, found an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357013/asking-an-intentservice-for-information-about-its-queue?lq=1). If I make the variable public, i will be able to access everywhere in may app, but I dont want this anyway.

Comment: One other problem with this answer: Your shared prefs data will persist - e.g., on device reboot - whereas your intents won't...